# How to cast pointZM geometry field to point in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, geometry

I have a table A with geometry(PointZM, 80001) type and another empty table B with geometry(Point, 80001) type and I want to insert data from table A to table B and I need to do a cast.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using PostGIS, you can use [ST_Force2D](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force2D.html) to cast `geometry(PointZM)` (3D with M value) to `geometry(Point)` (2D).

Comment: Is this can be applied to ListString and Polygon too ?

Comment: According to the doc, it works with LineStrings and Polygons

Comment: Thanks a lot brother ... but you know what can I do about z dimension ?

Comment: @Obtice ST_Force2D — Force the geometries into a "2-dimensional mode". ST_Force3D — Force the geometries into XYZ mode. This is an alias for ST_Force3DZ. ST_Force3DZ — Force the geometries into XYZ mode. ST_Force3DM — Force the geometries into XYM mode. ST_Force4D